# Whats does % mean in Python? Have trouble understanding

Tags: python

I have searched the forums for a little bit now and I am still very confused. If someone could direct me to an article that explains this more in depth I would greatly appreciate it. I am taking an intro to python course and I found the solution to my problem, but I want to actually know how\why it works. The assignment is to return the batting average for a player, and display it as the MLB would display. So for example 4hits in 8 at bats would be .500. Here is the code I found that works.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

def print_batting_average(at_bats, hits):
    average_str = "%.3f" % (hits / at_bats)
    if average_str.startswith("0"):
        average_str = average_str[1:]
    print("Batting average is", average_str)

print_batting_average(4, 2)
```

I know the % is modulus and gives the remainder of something. I just don't understand how that fits into other parts of code. For example the "%.3f". I have also seen the % used in different ways, and I just wanted to find a good explanation. Hopefully I don't get flamed for positing this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context you are asking about the `%` is used to help format output, and has nothing to do with any mod operation.

For instance, `%3d`, `%.2f` are all different ways to format output. The first example means you want to display an integer and reserve 3 spaces for it. The 2nd one means you want to display a float type value with 2 numbers after the decimal point.

See`String Formatting Operations` in
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations  for more information and details about the various formatting types and options.

You may come across something like this:

```
number_of_Widgets = 5
cost = 66.8788
print 'Total cost for %d widgets is $ %5.2f.' % (number_of_Widgets, cost)
```

yields:

```
Total cost for 5 widgets is $ 66.88.
```

The part enclosed in ' ' uses formatting instructions as place holders for the actual variable values supplied in toward the end of the line. The values are preceded by the % and then the () contain the variables that supply the values.

Here is a simple example as to why the format strings can come in handy for formatting your output:

Here we don't reserve and additional space for the number and you can see it shifting the output when it reaches 10.

```
In [9]: for i in xrange(5,15):
   ...:     print '%d is the number' % i
   ...:
5 is the number
6 is the number
7 is the number
8 is the number
9 is the number
10 is the number
11 is the number
12 is the number
13 is the number
14 is the number
```

Here we format the number with two spaces, and get a leading blank space for single digit numbers.

```
In [10]: for i in xrange(5,15):
   ....:     print '%2d is the number' % i
   ....:
 5 is the number
 6 is the number
 7 is the number
 8 is the number
 9 is the number
10 is the number
11 is the number
12 is the number
13 is the number
14 is the number
```

Comment: This is the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you very much for this detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

% in an arithmetic expression means modulus.

% inside a literal string like "%.3f" is just a normal character; it has nothing to do with modulus.

But strings with % signs inside them are special when you use them in conjunction with the % operator.   In this case, the value on the left is a string, so the modulus meaning doesn't apply; instead, you get formatting.  The %-sequences inside the string are placeholders that get replaced by the values in the tuple, formatted according to what comes after each '%' in the string.  For i nstance,  "%.3f" means "a floating point value with three digits after the decimal point.".

See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting for details on the format specifications; it's approximately the same as the `printf` family of functions in C.

Comment: Is there someone I can go to see all of the values for this type of string? You have touched on some of the things I have read, but to be honest I am still confused. I have only been working with python for a few weeks.

Comment: @AustinTheNoob see the link I provided in my answer, section 5.6.2 of http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: Specifically see the http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting subsection.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but `(hits / at_bats)` is not a tuple, it evaluates to just a number. `(hits / at_bats,)` would be a tuple. Either would work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
"%.3f" % (hits / at_bats)
```

the percent sign is used in two different ways, neither of which is related to the modulus operator.

Specifically:

- the second `%` is the [string formatting operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations);
- the first `%`is used in conjunction with the first, and defines the actual format used.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/string.html

> “Format specifications” are used within replacement fields contained
>   within a format string to define how individual values are presented
>   (see Format String Syntax.) They can also be passed directly to the
>   builtin format() function. Each formattable type may define how the
>   format specification is to be interpreted.

The modulus function in Python is just `mod(p,q)`

Answer (score 0):

The `%` used to format strings is not the same as the modulus operator. Notice how it's inside quotes.

`%` for string formatting is a standard and convention in many programming languages - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string