# How to use % symbol correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have searched on the google but I did not find correct answer

I have the following code:

```
print("i have %d years old" % (15))
```

Is there a perfect references to learn how to use above way fully ?

Comment: I don't think you searched very hard... By the way, asking for references (links, books, tutorials, etc) to external resources is considered off-topic for SO and is grounds to have your question closed.

Comment: 1. Strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964930/python-string-formatting-with-percent-sign 2. Modulo / numeric http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961344/what-does-the-percentage-sign-mean-in-python-3-1

Comment: @Hack-R: You are being a little hasty.  The question here is how to use `%`.  The question you linked is asking why a particular use of it throws a syntax error.

Comment: A better dupe target is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238306/what-does-do-to-strings-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats does % mean in Python? Have trouble understanding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338011/whats-does-mean-in-python-have-trouble-understanding)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"%" is actually the modulus operator but it can also be used to format strings.
Learn more about it here: [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=28790&seqNum=2)